# "File descriptor in bad state" error while running ffmpeg on android device and selecting an input device

Tags: android, file-io, ffmpeg

Below is the output of the ffmpeg command:**# ./ffmpeg -y -f s16le -i /dev/snd/pcmC3D0c 1640.wmv**  -to create an audio file from a Logitech webcam on an android device.
As shown in the output, I received  a  **File descriptor in bad state error**  for referring to the mic input as  **/dev/snd/pcmC3D0c**  I determined the value of the device (webcam mic) by reviewing the contents of **/proc/asound**. The webcam mic was card3 and its **STREAM0** file indicated that the mic has an audio format of format **S16_LE**
 It was also confirmed that it is a capture device and its' pcm id was **pcmC3D0c (C3 being the card number and D0 being the Device number**. I then confirmed the correct device by checking the  **/dev/snd/** directory to confirm its proper and full description. The /dev/snd folder confirmed that the mic was  **/dev/snd/pcmC3D0c**
I then checked the permissions and ownership to make sure that I could use that device. Hence as far as identifying the correct device to used I do believe that **/dev/snd/pcmC3D0c** is the correct device. I do believe this error could possibly have something to do with the OS, however after all these checks, I still cannot figure out what is giving the bad file descriptor state error.
Please note that I tested for different output formats, etc and that did not make any difference. Any leads or suggestions?

# ./ffmpeg  -y -f s16le -i /dev/snd/pcmC3D0c 1640.wmv

> ffmpeg version N-43170-gd84dd35 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Aug 24 2012 09:16:05 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC) configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/output --enable-pic --cross-prefix=/home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --extra-cflags=-I../x264 --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -lc'
>         libavutil      51. 66.100 / 51. 66.100
>     libavcodec     54. 48.100 / 54. 48.100
>     libavformat    54. 22.100 / 54. 22.100 
>     libavdevice    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100 
>     libavfilter     3.  5.102 /  3.  5.102
>     libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
>     libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
>     libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
>   [s16le @ 0xfd84f0] Invalid sample rate 0 specified using default of 44100
>   [s16le @ 0xfd84f0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>   Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
>   Input #0, s16le, from **'/dev/snd/pcmC3D0c':**
>     Duration: N/A, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Output #0, asf, to '1640.wmv':
>     Metadata:
>       WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf54.22.100
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> wmav2)
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   **/dev/snd/pcmC3D0c: File descriptor in bad state**
>   size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
>   video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 5340.000000%

Answer (score 0):

you may need to introduce an OS pipe in order to handle the live audio... ffmpeg has well documented scripted samples for using pipes.

see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1544946)

Based on your scenario, you might also look at VLC in addition to ffmpeg.

Comment: @rowntreerob -Robert,this question arises from an implementation of your version of FFMPEG for android. The ffmpeg is being used on Android box. I am supposed to design and teach an FFMPEG for Android course to a community programming club in Vancouver, BC, Canada. Could I contact you outside this forum? I promise not to take too much of your time. I built an Ubuntu ver. of ffmpeg which contains the alsa input device; however your version of FFMPEG DOES NOT build and include alsa. The course is about the use of v4l2 and alsa. Please check your build of the CL version to see if alsa was created

Comment: http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/compil-ffmpeg-with-alsa-support-td942078.html  go to thread's end and c 2nd-to-last post

Comment: verify that your system has the alsa drivers and then adjust the 'configure_ffmpeg.sh' to include alsa...


usr$ apt-cache search alsa | grep driver 
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files

Comment: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3513/record-mp3-audio-via-alsa-using-ffmpeg   u could split to 2 separate processes using this.